# I have an Apache2 CGI executable trying to use setgid()/setuid(). But it fails switching to root. How do I fix that issue?

Tags: permissions, systemd, apache-httpd, setuid, setgid

My [CGI executable starts as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547414/running-binary-cgi-on-apache2/1421670#1421670). At some point, though, it tries to become root (and then yet a different user). At that point, the CGI fails.

Here is the pertinent code snippet:

```
[...]

int const pid(fork());
if(pid == 0)
{
    if(setgid(0) == -1)    // <-- this fails.
    {
        std::cerr << "error: cannot become the \"root\" group.\n";
        exit(0);
    }

[...]
```

I was thinking it could have something to do with the systemd [`NoNewPrivileges`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) parameter. That parameter is set to `false` by default and it does not appear in the Apache2 `.service` file. So I'm wondering what I could try next to make it all work.

Here is the `apache2.service` file (on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and we can see that `NoNewPrivileges` is not set, nor [a field with a similar side effect as listed on Freedesktop](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Security).

How do I get the `setuid()`/`setgid()` functions to work in newer versions of Apache2?

Comment: What user is Apache running the CGI as? Generally Apache drops root privs so is not running as root at that point.

Comment: @thrig Which is why my CGI has its setuid flag set. It's running as `www-data`, which is the default on Ubuntu.

Comment: AppArmor issue?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried a click on the same link to see whether it would get me some logs in the `/var/log/auth.log` and it worked?! 3 days ago, I was fighting with this. Since then, though, I did a reboot. I don't see why a reboot would have fixed anything, though. In any event, it's resolved now!

Comment: As far as I understand a binary can only use setuid or setgid, if the suid or sgid bit is set on the binary. Is it set?

Comment: @bananabook Yes. That's the first thing I verified. I had another issue which was that the folder `/cgi-bin/` would not work. Once I finally changed it to `/cgi/`, the process started. I also don't understand that one. It could be that the `s` bit was not set when I was finally able to start the process (I removed it at some point to make sure it wasn't what would prevent the binary to start in the first place—but that `/cgi-bin/` was somehow the culprit!?)